# single mysql query to update quantity based on selecting quantity of another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have the following 2 queries that i was wondering if i can merge into a single statement.

```
$sql = "SELECT sale_qty FROM sale_device WHERE id = '$id' ";
```

and

```
$sql = "UPDATE device SET qty = $sale_qty WHERE id = $deviceId";
```

i want to run a select query to get the current quantity of a device from a row, then use that value minus one in a update query to set the new quantity, but don't allow it under 0

is this possible or advised to join? or would it be easier to just run 2 queries?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  I think this does what you want:

```
UPDATE device
    SET qty = (SELECT greatest(sale_qty - 1, 0)
               FROM sale_device
               WHERE id = '$id'
              )
    WHERE id = $deviceId
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I think this should work:

```
UPDATE Device D
   JOIN Sale_Device SD ON D.Id = SD.DeviceId
SET D.qty = GREATEST(SD.sale_qty-1,0)
WHERE SD.Id = '$id'
```

This assumes the `Sale_Device` table has a `DeviceId` field.